# Control input sum in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

if cell a1=25+30+40+10.is there a formula to get cell b1 to equal a1 Except for all the numbers less than 25? so it will be b1=30+40.

Comment: Do you mean A1 literally has the `=25+30+40+10` in it? What version of Excel are you using? Does the solution have to work on other versionsof Excel?

Comment: BTW, this would be easy in VBA for a wide variety of Excel versions. Can you use a VBA User Defined Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Formulatext and Filterxml function of which are available in Excel 2013 or above

In `A1`, enter : `=25+30+40+10`

In `B1` enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),2,99),"+","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[.>25]"))
```

[image]

Comment: work very good.thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a VBA UDF (aka *User Defined Function*). Copy the code and paste it into a VBA standard module code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Function AddendsIf(rng As Range, c As String)

    Dim i As Long, a As Variant, f As String, s As Double

    f = Mid(rng.Cells(1).Formula, 2)

    a = Split(f, "+")

    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)

        If Application.Evaluate(a(i) & c) Then

            s = s + Val(a(i))

        End If

    Next i

    AddendsIf = s

End Function
```

You can use it back at the worksheet just like any other native worksheet function.

[image]

[image]

If your version of Excel supports the [FORMULATEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) then you should be able to couple that with the [FILTERXML function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7) to achieve something similar.

---

<sub>An **[addend](https://study.com/academy/lesson/addend-in-math-definition-lesson-quiz.html)** is each individual value that makes up a sum.</sub>

Comment: ..................extremely clever approach................